# there is a way to call an method exclude some url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I need to call this method when the url DOESN't contains the character "API". I'm new spring and I dont' know if I can do this. The method is

```
@Controller 
public class RouterController { 
     //here I need to call method when the url doesn't contains the word "api"
  @RequestMapping({"/api*"}) 
    public String app() { 
   ...
  } 
}
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using : **^(?!api$).*$**

```
@Controller 
public class RouterController { 
     //here I need to call method when the url doesn't contains the word "api"
  @RequestMapping({"/^(?!api$).*$"}) 
    public String app() { 
   ...
  } 
}
```